# VBA : i = i + 1 counter not working

Tags: vba, counter

I'am on VBA trying to create a macro that record in different cell the number of times the workbook is open. Each time it is open, it creates a new cell with the number of the opening. So I created a counter for that.

```
   Option Explicit 

   Dim i As Integer  

   Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
     If i = "" Then 
       i = 1 
     End If  

     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 1).Value = "Session " & i  
     i = i + 1
     Debug.Print i  
   End Sub
```

However, the statement If i = "" remains highlighted in yellow, and I don't understand why...
Would someone have a solution?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you cannot assign a string to an integer. This is a `type mismatch` error.

What you need is to fetch the last cell in the column and then increment it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Fetch the last cell from column 1
    Dim r As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feuil1")
        Set r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    End With

    ' Get the last session number, or 0 if not present or doesn't match
    Dim lastSession As Long: lastSession = 0
    If Not IsEmpty(r) Then
        Dim p As Long: p = InStr(1, Trim(r.value), "Session ")
        If p = 1 Then
            lastSession = CLng(Mid(r.value, p + Len("Session "), 10000))
        End If
    End If
    r.Offset(1).value = "Session " & (lastSession + 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is an `Integer` so comparison to an empty `String` is not valid.

The closest thing you can do is

`If i = 0 Then`

But if you want the value to `i` to *persist* when you save the workbook, the simplest thing to do is to read its value from the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go like follows

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Worksheets("Feuil1")
        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
            .Offset(1) = "Session " & Val(Replace(.Value, "Session ", "")) + 1
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Joliba, just curious if this code would have suited you

Comment: @Joliba, doesn't matter, I will survive without your feedback as well!